# Create module over class

Tags: c#

I have a class called `Version`. It have informations about how application will work dependings of selected version of a sub-product. For each sub-product I have modules. So I create a abstract class called `Module`. And each module inherit from this class. For instance: `People: Module`, `Checklist: Module`, etc.

My problem is that I need get an unique instance of a Module over Version. So I did it:

```
class Version {
    private Dictionary<string, Module> LoadedModules = new ...;

    public GetModule(Type paramModuleType) {
        // If instance yet was created, so return it.
        if(LoadedModules.ContainsKey(paramModuleType.Name)) { 
            return LoadedModules[paramModuleType.Name];
        }

        // Else, it will be created and stored for next call.
        return LoadedModules[paramModuleType.Name] = 
            (Module) Activator.CreateInstance(paramModuleType, this);
    }
}
```

But I want get a Version Module using directly the Module. For instance:

```
var clientModule = ClientModule.From(versionInstance);
```

I tried create a method called `From(Version paramVersion)` on `Module` abstract class but it doesn't works. I think that I'm doing it thinking wrong.

```
public abstract class Module {
    public Version Version;

    protected Module(Version paramVersion) {
        Version = paramVersion;
    }

    static public Module From(Version paramVersion) {
        return paramVersion.GetModule(typeof(Module));
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you didn't know, there is a well-known type (in `System` namespace) called `Version` already...

Comment: In my case, Version is about other thing (related to my product). But thanks. :)